# differences between gcc -mcpu at runtime vs. buildin --with-cpu

Tags: gcc, arm, crosstool-ng

What are the differences between compiling for arm with the `-mcpu` option (e.g. `-mcpu=cortex-a9`) versus omitting the mcpu option and having build the toolchain by crosstool-ng with `CT_ARCH_CPU` (the `--with-cpu` option e.g. `--with-cpu=cortex-a9`).

The crosstool-ng menuconfig help text specifies that `CT_ARCH_CPU`:

> ... is the configuration flag --with-cpu=XXXX, and the runtime flag -mcpu=XXX.

And the gcc documentation states:

> --with-cpu=cpu
>
> Specify which cpu variant the compiler should generate code for by default. cpu will be used as the default value of the -mcpu= switch.

(see https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html)

Which implies -mcpu and --with-cpu do both the same, but it seems they behave differently, as shown in question:

[Crosstool-ng g++ not compiling c++11 std::current_exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44758575/crosstool-ng-g-not-compiling-c11-stdcurrent-exception)

Comment: Which flag is your library built with?  Think about it...  Also your defines will alter depending on which `-mcpu` is in effect.  Capture `gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null` and see the difference.  You library (without multi-lib) will be build with code generation and C defines as per the `with-cpu`.